# Vue and api background changing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to change a background of a joke that is taken from an Api, The problem is that the background won't change and i can't figure out the reason.
Where i am having problems is that i cant figure out how to change the properties of an object inside the data.
I was able to change the background when i changed from flags to catergory. Where am i going wrong. Did i misunderstand somthing?

the vue.js

```js
    let jokeIng = new Vue({
    el: "#JokeApp",
    data: function () {
        return {
            randomJoke: "",
            jokeLists: "",
            ownJoke: null,
            selected: null,
            color: 'green',

        };
    },
    methods: {
        getData: function () {
            axios.get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any").then((ret) => {
                console.log(ret);
                this.randomJoke = ret.data;
                this.changeColor(ret.data.flags);
            });
        },
        changeColor: function (value) {
            switch (value) {
                case 'nsfw':
                    this.color = 'red';
                    break;
                case 'racist':
                    this.color = 'blue';
                    break;
                case 'sexist':
                    this.color = 'yellow';
                    break;
                case 'explicit':
                    this.color = 'orange';
            
            }
        },
```

the html

````html
<div id="Color" :style="{'background-color':color}">
                        <div class="jokeTxt">{{randomJoke.data}}</div>

                        <div class="rjoke">
                            {{randomJoke.joke}} <br />
                            {{randomJoke.setup}} <br />
                            {{randomJoke.delivery}}
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API returns JSON objects like this:

```js
{
    "error": false,
    "category": "Programming",
    "type": "twopart",
    "setup": ".NET developers are picky when it comes to food.",
    "delivery": "They only like chicken NuGet.",
    "flags": {
        "nsfw": false,
        "religious": false,
        "political": false,
        "racist": false,
        "sexist": false,
        "explicit": false
    },
    "id": 49,
    "safe": true,
    "lang": "en"
}
```

`flags` is an object that maps the categories to Booleans, but `changeColor()` is incorrectly comparing `flags` to strings in the `switch` statement.

The fix is to check for each flag individually:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    changeColor(flags) {
      if (flags.nsfw) {
        this.color = 'red'
      } else if (flags.religious) {
        this.color = ''
      } else if (flags.political) {
        this.color = ''
      } else if (flags.racist) {
        this.color = 'blue'
      } else if (flags.sexist) {
        this.color = 'yellow'
      } else if (flags.explicit) {
        this.color = 'orange'
      } else {
        this.color = ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can see where i was going wrong with this. This is all new to me so thanks again for taking the time to answear. Google was't very helpful about this so asking here was a hail mary :)